# Как убрать вставки <style> в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я уже не знаю, что удалить. А данные вставки остаются. Все что находилось в папке `resources`, код удалил весь. Что нужно удалить, чтобы их убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

единственная `view` `resources\views\welcome.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Styles -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Documentation</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а что во вьюшке то самой?

Comment: Что в layout написано, то и получили...  Ищите вьюху да выпиливайте

Comment: @PaulWall, добавил код вьюшки

Comment: @VladimirGonchar добавил код вьюшки

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев не, это вьюшка экстендит другую вьюшку, она скорее всего у вас там в layouts/master.blade.php

Comment: @PaulWall это где такое? не могу найти ничего подобного

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев вы что ли выпилили layouts и в welcome.blade зпросто впихнули все? если нет, то скиньте содержимое папки views

Comment: @PaulWall, ничего вообще не трогал. В папке `resources/views/` лежит один файл `welcome.blade.php`. В `route` прописана одна строка `return view('welcome');`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев можете показать примерное содержимое тех стилей и скриптов? может понятнее будет тогда

Comment: @PaulWall, спасибо за помощь. это были вставки от плагинов в браузере.

Answer (score -1):

[Согласно ТС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934499/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-style-%D0%B2-laravel/936576#comment1550687_934499), `это были вставки от плагинов в браузере`

Например АД блок можно попробовать выключить. Этот код вставляет он в опере или хроме.

Comment: "спасибо за помощь. это были вставки от плагинов в браузере" как раз что я и отписал)

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/330450)

Comment: @AntonSorokin мою тревогу по этому ответу не приняли)